# Copy most recent revisions for each ID to new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I have 4 columns: `Number`, `Title`, `Revision`, `ID`.  Each row has a unique ID.  The sheet is grouped by ID and sorted so the newest revision is at the top.

I'm trying to create a new sheet with only the **most recent revisions for each ID**.

***My code:***

```
 Sub mySub()

    Dim j As Long
    j = 2 ' row 1 on sheet2 is headings

    Dim source As Excel.Worksheet 'source
    Dim target As Excel.Worksheet 'target
    Set source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("owssvr (1)") 'source sheet
    Set target = wb.Sheets.Add(Type:=xlWorksheet, _
        after:=Application.ActiveSheet) '("Sheet2") 'target sheet
    Sheets("owssvr (1)").Activate 'sheet with data

    For Each c In source.Range("D1:D5000") 'currently currently 5000 rows
        Dim alreadythere As Boolean 'already on sheet2?
        alreadythere = False 'not in sheet2 yet

' ***** "TYPE MISMATCH" ERROR on following line *****
        If c.Cells(4, 1).Value <> c.Offset(0, 1).Cells(4, 1).Value Then 

            For ctr = 1 To j 'checking from row 1 to last row in sheet2
                If c = target.Cells(ctr, 4) Then 'if it is in sheet2
                    alreadythere = True 'already exists
                End If
            Next ctr
            If alreadythere = False Then 'if its not in sheet2 already
                 source.Rows(c.Row).Copy 'copy
                 target.Rows(j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste
                 Application.CutCopyMode = False 'fix mode
                 j = j + 1 'count new row
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

**Data Example and Expected outcome:**

```
Number    Title    Revision    ID
1        Title 1     C       GH6YY
1        Title 1     B       GH6YY
1        Title 1     A       SDF212
2        Title 2     B       SDF212
2        Title 2     A       SDF212
3        Title 3     B       GTR3000
3        Title 3     A       GTR3000
3        Title 4     C       RTT24
3        Title 4     B       RTT24
3        Title 4     A       RTT24
```

**Expected Outcome:**

```
Number   Title    Revision   ID
1        Title 1     C       GH6YY
2        Title 2     B       SDF212
3        Title 3     B       GTR3000
3        Title 4     C       RTT24
```

Comment: Pivot table perhaps?

Comment: What is a pivot table?

Comment: I thought *I* talked too much...  :-)  I removed everything except for the relevant parts, and tidied your code.  I'm not sure if the comments were just for yourself but they were making the code harder to follow.  (...On a programming site, you don't need to explain what `+1` and `=TRUE` mean)  **:-)**

Comment: Pivot tables might not help...  Question to confirm:   the target sheet should have one of each ID... based on the `Number` or the "highest letter" is `Revision`?  (Like `B > A` ?  If so, what happens when you get to `Z`?)

Comment: After Z is AA, AB, AC, and so on until ZZ

Comment: The target sheet should have one of each ID based on the revision. The number and title columns can be ignored in this fragment

Comment: And that's what you want to sort the revision by?  Did you choose this method (so it can be changed to a "modern-day" method of organization) or is this coming from somewhere else (and has to stay)?  It's not impossible but it adds a potentially needless complication.

Comment: I think you're asking if I can switch ABCD to 1234? If so, no, they have to stay as letters because I am getting them from somewhere else. The excel sheet is already organized by newest to oldest, though

Comment: I'm not very familiar with VBA syntax, but what I am trying to do is loop through the ID column and every time I find something new, add the whole row to the target sheet

Comment: Is it perhaps because you have `For Each c In source.Range("D1:D5000")` ...meaning, for each cell in the range.  Then, when you call `c.Cells(4,1)` it's throwing an error because you can't ask for "row 4, column 1" of a *single cell*.  You either need `OFFSET()`, or perhaps you mean `For Each c In source.Range("D1:D5000").Rows` and switch to `c.Cells(1,4)`??

Comment: I tried to compare c with (c+1) but it also gave me a type mismatch. I'm not sure if using a range was the best approach but I don't know how to loop through a sheet and use variables as coordinates instead of numbers

Comment: I can think of a **much** easier way to do this.  Just a question first:  Does the list *need* to be on a separate worksheet?  (Are you further manipulating the data on the other sheet or is it just for reference?) If you could click a button on this worksheet to toggle between  `"view all"` and `"view most recent only"`, would that work for you?

Comment: a toggle would work fine I think

Comment: I'll just be a couple minutes to write an answer with an example.  :)

Comment: Is your revision column actually filled with the letters A, B, C (denoting order)? Or is there some kind of "Revision Date" field that helps you identify what the latest revision is?

Comment: there is a revision date which is how I organized it already, but the sheet is already in order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually a few ways this can be accomplished in seconds without even using VBA.  Here's one way.

Using your sample data as an example, in columns A to D, and we want to hide everything except the *first* occurrence of each ID:

- In cell `E2` enter formula:

  ```
  =COUNTIF($D$2:D2,D2)
  ```

  ...and then copy or "fill" it down to row 5000 or however far your data goes.  (If necessary, **insert** a new column first -- you can always **hide** it when you're done setting this up.)
- Under the `Data` menu, click `Filter`.
- In the *Filter* menu on column `E`, choose to only show values of `1`.

Everything disappears except the most recent.  At the bottom of the screen you'll see a count of total & displayed rows.  Another advantage to this method is will work even if the columns are NOT in order.

[image: img]

Now I know this isn't a *toggle button* but it's pretty darn close.  Just for the heck of it I'll slap together some code for a button too. (So yeah technically it uses VBA - except I'm going to make Excel write the code for me!)   ...

---

### "Toggle" Command Button:

Add a command button and attach the following code to it (changing the name of the button and the auto-filter columns if necessary)

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1").TextFrame.Characters
        If .Text <> "Show All" Then
             'only most recent
            .Text = "Show All"
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$11").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="1"
        Else
            'show all
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$11").AutoFilter Field:=5
            .Text = "Show Most Recent"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: img2]

---

### How to sort by your letter/numbering system

As mentioned, your numbering system of `A→Z→AA→ZZ→ etc` leaves a lot to be desired, especially since Excel doesn't sort letter that way.  (Alphabetically,`AA` comes long before `Z`.)

But I had an idea: if necessary you could use this "sneaky" method of getting the "number" from the letters, based on Excel's column numbers.

**Worksheet Formula:**

```
=COLUMN(INDIRECT(A1&"1"))
```

**VBA Functiom:**

```
Function numberFromRevision(revStr As String) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    numberFromRevision = Range(revStr & "1").Column
End Function
```

Both return results like this:

[image: img]

**Maximum column**:`XFD` = 16384 revisions.  This could be handy in a number of ways you haven't even considered yet.   :)

Comment: When you say the =COUNTIF($D2$2:D2,D2) works even if the sheet is not in order, does that mean it will work if the revisions are not in order?

Comment: also, the data in the sheet is extracted from another website. so if I wanted to make something that could automate any sheet could I make something to paste that formula in the last column and would it work?

Comment: No - I can see how that cab be misinterpreted.  It will still count the "top-most" occurrence of each ID as #1, even if unrelated ID's are inserted in between.  An array formula *could* be used to determine the newest revision even if they are completely mixed up, **but** the "A->Z, AA->ZZ numbering" system would need special consideration... although I was thinking about that.  **I'll add a tricky formula & function to the end of my answer to convert the revision letters to a "sortable" number** in a couple minutes.   An alternate way would be to add the date of entry to each row.

Comment: I have a column M for date of entry, it's how I sorted it before, but what bugs me is when I recorded a macro to custom filter the sheet by number then ID then date, it only does it if the sheet is the same name as the one I recorded

Comment: As for pasting the formula, I would record a macro of yourself entering the formula into the first cell and then double clicking the "autofill" handle in the bottom-right of the cell, then adjusting the generated code as necessary.  You'd use something like:  `Range("E2").Formula = "your formula here"` (next line:) `Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E5000")` (or better yet, a formula to using `xlEnd` to figure out the *actual* end of the data.